# Extracting information from lists

Tags: python, list, range

I have two lists I would like to compare and create another list as a result

```
list1 = [0.5, 1]
list2 = [0.0, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6. 0.75, 0.99, 1]
```

I would like to create a third list, containing all the numbers from list2 between 2 elements in list1

```
list3 = [0.5, 0.6, 0.75, 0.99, 1]
```

I tried:

```
 for i in range(list1[0], list1[1], step):
    print i
```

but my step is not the same in each case, so it does not work, what else could I try?

Cheers!

Comment: you might be able to do a lamba/map function here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`range` only returns integers.  You probably want something like this:

```
for i in list2:
    if i > list1[0] and i < list1[1]:
        print i
```

You may want to change `>` to `>=` and `<` to `<=` if needed.

If you want to construct list3 directly try:

```
list3 = [i for i in list2 if i > list1[0] and i < list1[1]]
```

**Edit**

For good measure, you can also do (which is how you would write it mathematically):

```
list3 = [i for i in list2 if list1[0] < i < list1[1]]
```

Comment: In Python, you don't need to use `and` for this sort of test.  You can directly write `list1[0] <= i <= list1[2]` and it does the right thing.

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = [0.5, 1]
list2 = [0.0, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.75, 0.99, 1]

low, high = list1
lst = [x for x in list2 if low <= x <= high]
print(lst)
```

Just for readability, we unpack the first list into two variables, `low` and `high`.

We use a list comprehension to get values from `list2`.  The list comprehension has a "filter" expression to select just the values we want.

It is better to directly iterate over the values of the list, than to try to use `range()` to get indices into the list.  The code is easier to write, easier to read, and as a bonus it's faster.

The list comprehension solution is the recommended way to solve this problem in Python.

Matthew Graves suggested that "you might be able to do a lamba/map function here".  I'll explain how to do that.

`filter()` needs you to pass in a function; you can define a function, or use the `lambda` keyword to make an anonymous function.  A `lambda` must be a single expression, but luckily in this case that's all we need.

```
low, high = list1
def check_low_high(x):
    return low <= x <= high

lst = list(filter(check_low_high, list2))

lst = list(filter(lambda x: low <= x <= high, list2))
```

In Python 2.x you don't really need to call `list()` because `filter()` returns a list.  In Python 3.x, `filter()` is "lazy" and returns an iterator.